# trying to add a flash video to a page using osflv but code not producing end result

Tags: html

I'm new to coding and trying to practice this piece of code but when I launch the code I only get the player and when I press the play button nothing appears.
I've been at this for 3 days now and I am unsure what needs to be corrected. I'm studying html&css design and build websites by Jon Duckett and even he told me what needed to be corrected but the code isn't producing the same results as his code.
If anyone can point out a solution that would be so helpful.
the sample piece can be downloaded here http://www.htmlandcssbook.com/code-samples/
It's chapter 9 adding a flash video.

Here is my piece of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Adding a Flash Video</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {};
    var params = {
      movie: "file:///C:/Users/billee/Videos/puppy/puppy.flv"
    };
    swfobject.embedSWF("file:///C:/Users/billee/Videos/flash/osplayer.swf",
      "snow", "400", "320", "8.0.0",
      flashvars, params);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="snow">
    <p>A video of a puppy playing in the snow</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The code only produces a blank page with no player or video. When I launch the code I only see a blank webpage showing only the text A video of a puppy playing in the snow

Comment: `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax.libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js` - This URL doesn't work. I get a 404 error. I think you want `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js`.

Comment: @BSMP ok I tried that and still getting a blank page, I even tried to download the swfobject.js local hd and change the path to point to that and still getting a blank page when launch code